# Capture a substring of a matched group

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, capturing-group

**Scanario**

I have to grab a substring from a composed string.
Match condition:

- string starts with 'section1:'
- captured string may be a blank separated or a dash separated list of alphanumerical values
- if the captured string ends with a specific suffix ('-xx'), exclude the suffix from the captured string.

**Examples**

*section1:ypsilon* : section 1 matches, grab 'ypsilon'

*section1:ypsilon zeta* : section 1 matches, grab 'ypsilon zeta'

*section1:ypsilon-zeta* : section 1 matches, grab 'ypsilon-zeta'

*section1:ypsilon-xx* : section 1 matches, grab 'ypsilon', exclude '-xx'

*section1:ypsilon zeta-xx* : section 1 matches, grab 'ypsilon zeta', exclude '-xx'

*section1:ypsilon-zeta-xx* : section 1 matches, grab 'ypsilon-zeta', exclude '-xx'

*section2:ypsilon* : section 2 does not match

**Solution so far**

```
^section1:([a-zA-Z0-9\- ]+)(\-xx)?$
```

The idea is to get the group 1, whereas the group 2 is optional.
[Demo](http://regexr.com/3aupq).

**Question**

Unfortunately the suffix matches the group1 definition, as it is an alphabetic string with a dash. So the resulting captured strings does not exclude the suffix.

Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, the main problem you're facing is the greediness of operators.

`n+` will match as many `n` as possible, if we wish to reduce this we have to suffix it with `?`

I end up with this regex [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/dB0rN8/1)

```
^section1:([a-zA-Z0-9\- ]+?)(|-xx)$
```

Main difference is the `?` after the `+` to make it non-greedy (or reluctant) and I prefer to use alternation between empty and desire suffix instead of a group `(|-xx)` this match nothing OR `-xx` before the end of line.

I've no argument between both, matter of taste I think.

Answer (score 2):

Use alteration of -xx with a non capturing group and use `?` to make `+` not so ready that `-xx` is sucked up in the match:

```
(?<=^section1):([a-zA-Z0-9\- ]+?)(?:-xx|:)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jK2eZ3/1)

If you don't have the second `:` to use as a bookmark, use `$`:

```
(?<=^section1):([a-zA-Z0-9\- ]+?)(?:-xx|\s*$)
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/jK2eZ3/3)

Comment: Worth saying a word about the non-greedy operator,no ?